# Pulling data using wsdl

Tags: apex, wsdl, wsdl2apex

while pulling Account data from database using WSDL. On Account we had a field call billing Address. now in wsdl does we get billing address directly or will it pull billing city,billing country ....seperatly?

Comment: Is your WSDL custom built or you are using Enterprise or Partner WSDL?

Comment: In custom built we can get individual values if i'm not mistaken.   and what about enterprise?

Comment: For enterprise too you can get individual values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<complexType name="Account">
 <complexContent>
  <extension base="ens:sObject">
  <sequence>
   <element name="BillingCity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="BillingCountry" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="BillingCountryCode" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="BillingLatitude" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
   <element name="BillingLongitude" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
   <element name="BillingPostalCode" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="BillingState" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="BillingStateCode" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="BillingStreet" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="BillingUpdate_c__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
```

> From the enterprise WSDL its confirmed its separate